# SQL Server - Truncate Using DATALENGTH

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datalength

Is there a way to truncate an nvarchar using DATALENGTH? I am trying to create an index on a column, but an index only accepts a maximum of 900 bytes. I have rows that consist of 1000+ bytes. I would like to truncate these rows and only accept the first n characters <= 900 bytes.

Comment: This could be a symptom of a flaw in the design.  Why do you want to index a wide column?  Libraries don't shelve "The Bell Jar" next to "Farenheit 451" even though one begins "It was a p..." and the other starts "It was a q..."

Comment: I second that.  Why do you need to index a column that big?

Comment: We need to do searches on that column. We accommodate partial searches so we can trim the characters. It will take a lot of time to query a row if we do not index that column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can be this sql useful, Just update the table for that column.

```
Update Table
Set Column = Left(Ltrim(Column),900)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work. The DATALENGTH is different from the character length (LEN). Some of the rows in the column have special characters, so they take up more bytes.

Comment: Actually, this does work, but it should be 450, not 900. Thank you.

Comment: You know you'll loose data by updating the table, right?

Answer (score 0):

Create a COMPUTED COLUMN that represents the data you want to index, then create an index on it.

```
ALTER TABLE MyTable ADD ComputedColumn AS LEFT(LargeNVarcharColumn,900);

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX MyIndex ON MyTable
(
    ComputedColumn ASC
);
```

---

**Reference:**

- [computed_column_definition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186241.aspx)
- [Indexes on Computed Columns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189292.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Trim the column ,left or right side to 900 characters ,create a index on that column

```
ALTER TABLE usertable ADD used_column AS LEFT(nvarcharcolumn,900);
```

create a index on this used columm.it will work

Comment: I have trimmed the rows to 450 characters, but they still take up 1000+ bytes.

Comment: create a seprate the column using nvarchar column, that new column should have below 900 characters.build a index on new column , use that column

Comment: Sorry, this works but the value should be 450, not 900.